# Using Geonetwork as alternate CSW backend of Geonode

Tags: geonetwork, geonode, csw

I am trying to integrate Geonode with Geonetwork instead of default Pycsw catalogue backend.

I have changed the setting.py of geonode installation following this guide :
https://doc-geonode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/004_admin_workshop/003_csw_settings/

When I'm trying to download metadata through Geonode,  it redirects to geonetwork csw service endpoint without any query parameter (like layer uuid etc). Also Geonetwork is still empty.  Is there someone who have integrated these two platforms successfully ?

Comment: So I assume that you have to harvest the geonode metadata into geonetwork

Comment: Hello, Not exactly, I am trying to use geonetwork instead of pycsw as backend csw service. So I need to upload/import layers to geonode and store metadata into geonetwork instead of pycsw which is the default cataloging mechanism of geonode

Comment: So in geonode there'll be no metadata, only data? that doesn't sound correct.  What does the geonode GUI show to allow you to load and discover data if it isn't metadata?  don't think that pycsw  creates the geonode metadata, just provides a standards based interface to allow programmatic access to it.

Comment: As I understand from Geonode architecture, The Geonode platform uses Geoserver API and PyCSW API to import layer and metadata accordingly . Regarding Geonode's documentation, it says that is possible to use Geonetwork instead of PyCSW. That means you will able to use the Geonetwork as CSW service. However I followed the configuration they promote through setting.py config file but it seems geonode cannot upload/or retrieve data from geonetwork. When I switch back to PyCsw it works properly

Comment: Where is the metadata currently? For pycsw to be able to import metadata it must exist somewhere

Comment: When I have the default configuration (means PyCSW) the medata is stored into PyCSW. When I switch to Geonetwork I am not sure where they stored. However Geonetwork GUI seems empty. I suppose that Geonode keeps data into its database/tables as well .